# adding string ending "\" to all elements of a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I  have a  list of strings: `['John','William','Ken','Rogers']`. I   need  to prepend `"Corp\"` to each element in the list so that the  final  list looks  like  this:

```
['Corp\John','Corp\William','Corp\Ken','Corp\Rogers']
```

I tried   the  following:

```
 s=['John','William','Ken','Rogers']
 users=['Corp\\' + m for m in s]
 print(users)
```

The  output  gives  me

```
 ['Corp\\John','Corp\\William','Corp\\Ken','Corp\\Rogers']
```

If  I try `users=['Corp\' + m for m in s]` I get an obvious  error:

> "StringError EOL while  scanning string literal"

I would   need  each element  in the  exact form `'Corp\name'`,  as this   needs   to be used  in a   for loop  to validate  users  who are  eligible to login.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash. Replace one backslash with two.

Comment: Just `print(*users)`. The `\\` is added due to `list`s calling the object's `__repr__`.

Comment: the output you see is the representation (`repr`) of the list object (which can be used with `eval` to give you the list in python). But the actual value of each string is `'Corp\*'`.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard While I agree that technically this is a dupe, is it fair to think that without an understanding of `__repr__` vs `__str__` that a new user would arrive at that question based on this information?

Comment: @NathanielFord maybe but, I've answered a similar question 2 times already (yes, shame on me :-), you can tell OP that printing items directly will lead to the behavior they want but that doesn't answer *why* that happens. I think linking to the canonical on why this is is the best course of action.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Fair enough; that's why I went and found a link to S.O. documentation as well. Cheers!

Comment: @user3030010 if one of the answers have answered your question correctly, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark underneath it's score. That's how we indicate to the community what worked :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be a problem with how you're 'outputting' the list. Using the REPL:

```
>>> lsa = ["Corp\{}".format(item) for item in ls]
>>> print(lsa)
['Corp\\Jenna', 'Corp\\Wilma', 'Corp\\Katie', 'Corp\\Rebecca']
>>> for i in lsa:
...     print(i)
... 
Corp\Jenna
Corp\Wilma
Corp\Katie
Corp\Rebecca
```

As you can see, in the first `print`, that prints the full list, we see two slashes. This is because Python is saying that the second slash is escaped. In the second print, inside a `for` loop, we see that there is only one slash, because we are printing each item individually and the escape string is applied, yielding only a single slash.

Comment: I deleted my answer cause it'll be like yours. Thanks for pointing the oddities i din't pay attention.